# call array from function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im storing a little data in my jQuery. I want to call it from arrays with functions, but when I call the array it doesn't return any value. There's my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmfjdz29/2/)**

jQuery code

```
$('button').click(showInfo);

function showInfo(){
    var data = $(this).attr("dataid");
  //alert(data);
  dataArray(data);
  writeData(data);
}

function dataArray(call){
    var person1 = [{
        'name':'First Name',
        'position':'Director'
    }];
    var person1 = [{
        'name':'Second Name',
        'position':'Director'
    }];
}

function writeData(called){
    $('.person').removeClass('hidden');
  dataArray(called[0]);
  // write in divs
  $('.person .name').text(dataArray(called['name']));
  $('.person .position').text(dataArray(called['position']));
}
```

Comment: dataArray function does nothing but declare two variables and then does nothing with them. Also i think you meant to have `var person2` as the second variable, instead of 2 `var person1` lines

Comment: One basic thing is that if you want a function to return something you need to `return` something. Maybe you should just explain what you want to happen, because this code does not really reveal that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return something from your dataWrite call. in this case an object of objects with person data. then you can filter that by the name passed in.

```js
$('button').click(showInfo);

function showInfo() {
  var data = $(this).attr("dataid");
  //alert(data);
  writeData(data);
}

function dataArray() {
  var persons = {
    person1: {
      name: 'First Name',
      position: 'Director'
    },
    person2: {
      name: 'Second Name',
      position: 'Director'
    }
  };
  return persons;
}

function writeData(called) {
  $('.person').removeClass('hidden');
  //alert(called);
  // write in divs
  $('.person .name').text(dataArray()[called].name);
  $('.person .position').text(dataArray()[called].position);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button dataid="person1">Call person 1</button>

<button dataid="person2">Call person 2</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="person hidden">
  <span>Name: </span>
  <div class="name"></div>
  <br/>
  <span>Position: </span>
  <div class="position"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

1. `dataArray` function isn't returning anything so you need to change it to:

   ```
   function dataArray(call){
    return {
     person1 :{
         name:'First Name',
         position:'Director'
     },
     person1 :{
       name:'Second Name',
           position:'Director'
      }
    }[call];
   }
   ```
2. you need to access the key of the returned object , and that would be:

   ```
   $('.person .name').text(dataArray(called)['name']);
   $('.person .position').text(dataArray(called)['position']);
   ```

here's the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmfjdz29/4/)